# Is it possible to install npm manually?

Tags: node.js, terminal, npm

I seem to have accidentally uninstalled Node Package Manager whilst attempting to update it. As far as I can tell the only way to reinstall it would be to reinstall node all together and doing that looks pretty fiddly. What are my options?

I'm using OSX Yosemite

Comment: What do you mean fiddly? For most open source packages, it's worth using a proper package manager instead of installing from "for OSX" installer: I'd recommend installing `brew`, and then installing node with `brew install node`. Done.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As stated in the official documentation, you can install npm with the following command:

```
$ curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh
```

Source: https://github.com/npm/npm#fancy-install-unix

Comment: The link is dead. A new one is probably this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm/v/7.0.3.

Answer (score 2):

using homebrew you can install it pretty easy:

```
$ brew install npm
```

and what Mike said, using homebrew installing `node` is really easy.

i would even recommend using [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) for version management of nodejs/iojs, which is even easier and gives you the bonus of not needing `sudo`:

```
$ curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.25.4/install.sh | bash
$ nvm install your-node-version
$ nvm use your-node-version
```